# Unable to find module for event dispatcher

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
 import data from './localserver/data';
 import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
  export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {text: ''};

 }
 componentDidMount() {
  let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
  console.log('sadas',deviceWidth)
  }

 render() {
  var stylesubash={
  height: 200,
  width:200

   }
  return (
   <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 
   'column',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
     <TextInput
        style={stylesubash}
        placeholder="Enter your mobile no"
        placeholderTextColor={data.primarysColor}
        maxLength={10}
        keyboardType='number-pad'
      />

     </View>

    );
  }
  }


  AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);
```

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufZEa.jpg)

I am trying to get output but when I run the simulator it throws an error 
**Unable to find a module for event dispatcher**, and I have one doubt too is any other way to get screen size rather importing the dimension from react native

Comment: try to stop remote debugger and Dev Settings > JS Dev Mode is checked ...and reload

Comment: try to reset cache using this   `yarn start -reset-cache`

Comment: not working!!@HendEl-Sahli

Comment: not working@abhinandansharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem with your project setup, as I have just run your above code, I didn't find any problem , so please setup your new project , that might help you out with problem.

Comment: Do you want me to delete the whole project?

Comment: No , first try removing node module and reinstalling.
if that don't work , you can start with fresh project

Comment: what do you think about this problem sir?

Comment: works fine , and will be more helpful if you tell the reason

Answer (score 1):

delete the project from the simulator and  erase all content from the simulator under hardware. make sure debug remotely is off